# Нужно ли выделять запятыми уточнение "до исчезновения"?

Tags: запятые, уточнения

Хотя последнюю пару лет, до исчезновения, он становился все более отстранённым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это действительно уточняющий оборот, то он, по правилам, выделяется запятыми, реже - тире. Если же не воспринимать эти слова как уточнение, то выделять не нужно:

> Хотя последнюю пару лет, до исчезновения, он становился все более отстранённым. = Хотя последнюю пару лет, то есть до исчезновения, он становился все более отстранённым.
>
> Хотя последнюю пару лет до исчезновения он становился все более отстранённым. = Хотя последние до исчезновения два года он становился все более отстранённым.

Правило такое: Если при наличии двух обстоятельств времени второе из них не служит для ограничения понятия, выраженного первым, то оно не является уточняющим и запятая между обстоятельствами не ставится